# PHP print_r() Alternative: array printed twice

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm attempting to create an alternative to print_r() in PHP that will work with my company's colored logging software.  I ripped the initial source code off of an example on the PHP doc page for print_r(), added colors and recursion protection, and it's working pretty well.

However, there is one little thing that's irking me regarding my recursion protection.  Self-referential arrays will print twice before detecting recursion.  Here's my test code:

```
$array = array(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    $object = (object) array(
        'foo' => 'bar',
        'baz' => 'qux',
    ),
    $object,
);
$array[] = &$array;
$array[] = &$array;
logDebug($array);
```

Here's the output:

```
 ___________________________________________________________                                                                                                           
|                                                                                                                                                                      
:: 2013-11-15 17:02:06 ( debug ) :: test_SplitLog.php [23] ::                                                                                                          
| 
| Array (
| 
|       [0] => 1
|       [1] => 2
|       [2] => 3
|       [3] => Object [stdClass] {
| 
|             [foo] => "bar"
|             [baz] => "qux"
| 
|       }
|       [4] => Object [stdClass] {*** Recursion ***}
|       [5] => Array (
| 
|             [0] => 1
|             [1] => 2
|             [2] => 3
|             [3] => Object [stdClass] {*** Recursion ***}
|             [4] => Object [stdClass] {*** Recursion ***}
|             [5] => Array (*** Recursion ***)
|             [6] => Array (*** Recursion ***)
| 
|       )
|       [6] => Array (*** Recursion ***)
| 
| )
|___________________________________________________________
```

As you can see, the array is printing out once on the top level, then once again as an element within itself (element 5).  Once it arrives at element 6 however (and elements 5 and 6 in the internal array), it's printing the recurstion message.

I handle array recursion by adding an element with a very specific key to each array being logged.  If that key is later found in an array, it means that the array has already been converted to a string and it should be skipped.

I did some testing using normal print_r().  When I add the key, it immediately shows up in a print_r() of the array (makes sense).  I then iterate over each array element however and recursively call print_r() on it.  When the array comes to itself (element 5), print_r() shows that the marker element doesn't exist.

It seems on the one hand like a value vs reference thing - like I'm forgetting to add an & somewhere.  But the key does show up when element 6 comes around, as well as in both 5 and 6 of the recursive processing of the array.

My other thought was that something internal to the array needed to be reset before a reference would recognize the existence of the marker key.  I tried reset() to no avail.  Does anyone have any insight as to why this is acting this way?

Thanks!
~ Nate

Source:

```
/**
 * Alternative to print_r() that makes use of ANSIColor.  Adapted
 * from function in print_r() documentation on PHP site.
 */
public function convertRecursivelyToString(&$thing, $settings = array()) {
    //:: Init
    $object_dictionary = array();
    $array_dictionary  = array();
    $settings = (array) $settings;
    $palette  = $this->colorPalette();

    //:: Convert
    $string = $this->convertRecursivelyToStringHelper($thing, $object_dictionary, $array_dictionary, 0, $palette, $settings);

    //:: Undo Array Tracking
    foreach ($array_dictionary as &$array) {
        unset($array['__LogFormatter::convertRecursivelyToStringHelper()__']);
        unset($array);
    }

    //:: Return String
    return $string;
}

/**
 * Alias for LogFormatter::convertRecursivelyToString().
 */
public function printR(&$thing, $settings = array()) {
    return $this->convertRecursivelyToString($thing, $settings);
}

/**
 * Performs the actual recursive conversion.
 */
private function convertRecursivelyToStringHelper(&$thing, &$object_dictionary, &$array_dictionary, $level, $palette, $settings) {
    //:: Init
    $tval    = $thing; // value of $thing to eliminate reference
    $spaces  = "";
    $space   = " ";
    $newline = "\n";
    $title   = "";
    $array   = is_array($tval);
    $object  = is_object($tval);
    $output  = "";
    $title   = $level === 0 && isset($settings['initial_title']) ? $settings['initial_title'] : null;
    $obrace  = $level === 0 && isset($settings['initial_brace']) ? $settings['initial_brace'] : ($array ? '(' : '{');
    $cbrace  = $level === 0 && isset($settings['closing_brace']) ? $settings['closing_brace'] : ($array ? ')' : '}');

    //:: Generate Spaces And Tabs
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
        $spaces .= $space;
    }
    $tabs = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $level; $i++) {
        $tabs .= $spaces;
    }

    //:: Handle Recursion
    if (
        ($array && isset($tval['__LogFormatter::convertRecursivelyToStringHelper()__'])) ||
        ($object && isset($object_dictionary[spl_object_hash($tval)]))
    ) {
        if ($array) {
            $output = "Array $obrace*** Recursion ***$cbrace";
        } else {
            $output = "Object [" . $palette->dimYellow(get_class($tval)) . "] $obrace*** Recursion ***$cbrace";
        }

    //:: Handle Scalars
    } else if (is_scalar($tval) || is_null($tval)) {
        // booleans
        if (is_bool($tval)) {
            $output = $tval ? $palette->dimCyan('true') : $palette->dimRed('false');

        // null
        } else if (is_null($tval)) {
            $output = $palette->brightBlack('null');

        // strings
        } else if (is_string($tval)) {
            $output = '"' . $palette->dimGreen($tval) . '"';

        // everything else
        } else {
            $output = (string) $tval;
        }

    //:: Handle Arrays
    } else if ($array) {
        // title
        $title  = $title === null ? "Array" : $title;
        $output = $title . ' ' . $obrace . $newline . $newline;

        // contents
        $thing['__LogFormatter::convertRecursivelyToStringHelper()__'] = true; // prevents recursion
        reset($thing);
        $array_dictionary[] = &$thing;
        foreach($thing as $key => &$value) {
            if ($key !== '__LogFormatter::convertRecursivelyToStringHelper()__') {
                $string_value = $this->convertRecursivelyToStringHelper($value, $object_dictionary, $array_dictionary, $level + 1, $palette, $settings);
                $output .= $tabs . $spaces . "[" . $palette->brightGreen($key) . "] => " . $string_value . $newline;
            }
            unset($value);
        }
        $output .= $newline . $tabs . $cbrace;

    //:: Handle Objects
    } else if ($object) {
        // title
        $title  = $title === null ? "Object [" . $palette->dimYellow(get_class($tval)) . "]" : $title;
        $output = $title . ' ' . $obrace . $newline . $newline;

        // contents
        $object_dictionary[spl_object_hash($tval)] = true; // prevents recursion
        if ($object && ($tval instanceof Loggable)) {
            $output .= $tval->convertToLogString();
        } else {
            foreach($tval as $key => &$value) {
                $string_value = $this->convertRecursivelyToStringHelper($value, $object_dictionary, $array_dictionary, $level + 1, $palette, $settings);
                $output .= $tabs . $spaces . "[" . $palette->brightGreen($key) . "] => " . $string_value . $newline;
            }
        }
        $output .= $newline . $tabs . $cbrace;

    //:: Handle Other
    } else {
        $output = gettype($tval);
    }

    //:: Return
    unset($thing);
    unset($object_dictionary);
    unset($array_dictionary);
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install xdebug extension and use `var_dump` instead... There are several configurations you can do:

http://xdebug.org/docs/display